# Redirect specific pages to ://https Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, http, redirect, ssl

I am trying to redirect users from http to https on 4 specific URL's on my Wordpress website.
I'm having some difficulty so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my ht.access file.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
#force https for certain pages    
{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(\booking-step-1.php|\booking-step-2.php|\booking-step-3.php|\booking-step-4.php)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
# END WordPress
```

I am hoping it is something to do with how I have listed the sites that I would like to redirect to https instead of http. Thanks in advance for any help, I will be sure to choose the best working answer! :)

Comment: I assume you mean `https://` (in your question title) and `.htaccess`  instead of `ht.access` ?

Comment: Your RewriteRule match can be simplified to `^(?:booking-step-[1234]\.php)$`

Comment: Yes naomik I mean .htaccess. Thank you, but this has given me an "apache" error when trying to access my site.